# modify only last value in jsonb field

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have table with jsonb field

Example:

```
id   jsonb_t
1    [ {"x" : 1 , "y": 2} , {"x" : 2 , "y": 3} , {"x": 3, "y" : 4} ]
2    [ {"x" : 1 , "y": 3} , {"x" : 3 , "y": 3} , {"x": 8, "y" : 2} ]
3    [ {"x" : 1 , "y": 4} , {"x" : 4 , "y": 3} , {"x": 5, "y" : 9} ]
```

I want to modify table where **id = 3** *but only the last row in jsonb array of objects* , it means replace e.g. **"y":9** into **"y":8** , and increment **"x":5** by **1** to **"x":6** .
I can't figure out how to do it in one step (replace and increment should be done "in place" due to thousends rows in jsonb[] array field) , thanks in advance for help .

Comment: Is that really an array of `jsonb` or a `jsonb` that contains a json array (looks like the latter) - `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense.

Comment: This would be sooo much easier with a properly normalized model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some jsonb functions such alike

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('x', x, 'y', y))
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN row_number() over() = jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t) THEN
                  x + 1
                 ELSE
                  x
               END AS x,
               CASE
                 WHEN row_number() over() = jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t) THEN
                  y - 1
                 ELSE
                  y
               END AS y
          FROM t, jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_t) AS(x INT, y INT)
         WHERE id = 3) AS j
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bf1826e9f56425629a85892309db7e0c)</kbd>

where `jsonb_to_recordset` expands outermost array of objects as individual integer elements, then (in/de)crement them after determining match through use of `row_number` and `jsonb_array_length` functions, then go back to build up the jsonb value again within the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data looks like the column is in fact defined as `jsonb` not `jsonb[]` and the array is a proper JSON array (not an array of `jsonb` values)

If that is correct, then you can use jsonb_set() to extract and modify the value of the last array element:

```
update the_table
  set jsonb_t = jsonb_set(jsonb_t, 
                    array[jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t)-1]::text[], 
                    jsonb_t -> jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t)-1 || 
                        '{"y":8}' || 
                         jsonb_build_object('x', (jsonb_t -> jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t)-1 ->> 'x')::int + 1)
                 )
where id = 3
```

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.13.1.1.1) `jsonb_set()` takes three parameters: the input value, the path to the value that should be changed and the new value.

The second parameter `array[jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t)-1]::text[]` calculates the target position in the JSON array by taking its length and subtracting one to get the last element. This integer is then converted to a text array (which is the required type for the second parameter).

The expression `jsonb_t -> jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t)-1` then picks that array element and appends the `'{"y":8}'` which will replace the existing key/value pair with `y`. The expression

```
jsonb_build_object('x', (jsonb_t -> jsonb_array_length(jsonb_t)-1 ->>  'x')::int + 1
```

extracts the current value of the `x` key, converting it to an integer, increments it by one and builds a new JSON object with the key `x` that is also appended to the old value, thus replacing the existing key.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5ddb84994102e2db09f3e01857165461)